# Error Running Qualcomm fastRPC Calculator Example for Hexagon DSP on Snapdragon 820 (Ubuntu 16.04))

Tags: ubuntu, android-ndk, qualcomm, hexagon-dsp

I am trying to run the basic calculator example from the Hexagon SDK on the Open-Q 820 Development Kit (Snapdragon), but when trying to run the *calculator_walkthrough.py* python script to run the example the process fails.

I'm running the Hexagon SDK 3.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.2. The Android NDK is installed in the correct location (according to the Hexagon SDK documentation).

The example seems to run correctly up until the following point:

```
---- root/remount device ----
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
restarting adbd as root
remount succeeded
failed to copy '/home/kaz/Qualcomm/Hexagon_SDK/3.0/tools/elfsigner/getserial' to '/data//getserial': Is a directory
ERROR: testsig:-o is not a valid 32 bit integer
---- root/remount device ----
adbd is already running as root
remount succeeded
---- Push Android components ----
329 KB/s (32104 bytes in 0.095s)
168 KB/s (12940 bytes in 0.075s)
 ---- Push Hexagon Components ----
256 KB/s (17992 bytes in 0.068s)
---- Run Calculator Example Locally on Android ----

- starting calculator test
adspmsgd not supported
- allocate 4000 bytes from ION heap
- creating sequence of numbers from 0 to 999
- compute sum locally
- sum = 499500
- success

adspmsgd_stop failed
---- Run Calculator Example on aDSP ----

- starting calculator test
adspmsgd not supported
- allocate 4000 bytes from ION heap
- creating sequence of numbers from 0 to 999
- compute sum on the aDSP
Error: compute on aDSP failed

usage: /data/calculator <1/0 run locally> <1/0 logcat> <uint32 size>

adspmsgd_stop failed
Done
```

The device is definitely connected, and can be seen using the following command:

```
kaz@kaz:~/Qualcomm/Hexagon_SDK/3.0/examples/common/calculator$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
252020106151601286  device
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the Hexagon SDK, attempted to run the script when the device is in Safe Mode and Normal mode, checked that all required libraries are in the correct directories but cannot find a solution to the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/data/getserial already exists on your device as a directory.  Remove it and try again.

Comment: I can' seem to find /data/get serial on my device. I have searched for the it using the following command  'kaz@kaz:~$ find /home/kaz -name '*getserial*'' but can't find anything like the path above. I have also tried with three different laptops and the same error is given. I also have access to two Snapdragon 820 boards and the other one works perfectly fine, so I'm inclined to think that the problem is with the board itself.  Thanks for the help though.

Comment: have you tried 'adb shell ls -la /data' and look for 'getserial'?